# AngularJS not displaying API data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to AngularJS.  I am trying to retrieve firstname, lastname & State from an API, using a search functionality for a statecode, say, "DC" for ex.

I have modified to be simpler, and I still see no result on the page:

Here's my get:

```
    function ItemsController($scope, $http){
    $http.get("https://my.ncarb.org/Public/api/certification/search?statecode=dc")
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
      $scope.items = data;
  });
}
```

Here's a sample of my api:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "14e1047c-b811-40f7-8a21-780ae5edf1ed",
      "firstName": "Kent",
      "lastName": "Abraham",
      "city": "WASHINGTON",
      "stateCode": "DC",
      "countryCode": "USA"
    },]
}
```

and here's my HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="ItemsController">
    <h1>jSON Data</h1>
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.stateCode}}</td>
      </tr>  
    </table>
  </body>
```

But my output, upon inspecting, getting a 200 OK status, but nothing gets displayed on the page...Any reason why ?

Attached - Screenshot of response in Dev tools

[image: screen shot or response]

Comment: what does this line `$http.get($scope.state.statecode)
         .then(onStates);` meant? is it going to do correct ajax call?

Comment: In the get() method, I am trying to get all the statecodes

Comment: but does the statecode actually contain an URL? Did you verify that the data you're getting in `onstates` is correct?

Comment: statecode does not contail URL.  How do i verify the data i am getting in onState ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. `$http.get` returns a promise.

Here is the working sample.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ItemsController">
        <h1>jSON Data</h1>
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                <td>{{item.firstName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.stateCode}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular App & Controller:

```
var module = angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app').controller('ItemsController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://my.ncarb.org/Public/api/certification/search?statecode=dc').then(function (response) {
         // this callback will be called asynchronously
         // when the response is available
        $scope.items = response.data.data;
    }, function (response) {
          // called asynchronously if an error occurs
          // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
}]);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bhushan Firake, i copied your javascript/controller and it works like a charm.  So, for $http.get(), i should always append it with .then() ?

Comment: @Ron Happy to help. regarding `.then()`, I recomment you reading https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 1):

data is complete response from the api.

Just do :

```
$http.get("https://my.ncarb.org/Public/api/certification/search?statecode=dc")
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    $scope.items = data.data;
});
```

It will solve your problem :)

Comment: Thanks @Mahaveer Jain, will give it a try

Comment: @Ron glad to help you . you can try .then as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do a second $http.get() ? If the first one return the sample of the api it is useless because you should pass something that return a response in parameter of your $http.get()

Maybe you should make$scope.states = response.data just after the call of your API.