# Using $http in AngularJS + WebAPI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to print out list of categories using AngularJS on top of WebAPI. I have the following page and when I navigate to it, I get alert message containing "-1".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.service('categoriesService', function ($http) {
        delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        this.getData = function () {
            // $http() returns a $promise that we can add handlers with
.then()
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://www.example.com/api/categories'
            });
        }
    });

    myApp.controller('CategoriesCtrl', function ($scope, categoriesService) {
        $scope.data = null;
        categoriesService.getData().then(function (response) {
            $scope.data = response;
        }, function (response) {
            alert(response.status);
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div  ng-controller="CategoriesCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="category in data">
                {{ category.Name }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried samples from here:
[How to use HTTP.GET in AngularJS correctly? In specific, for an external API call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369377/how-to-use-http-get-in-angularjs-correctly-in-specific-for-an-external-api-cal)
and here
[AngularJS not displaying API data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234107/angularjs-not-displaying-api-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service returns a promise but when the promise resolves no data is returned:

```
this.getData = function () {
  return $http.get('https://www.example.com/api/categories').then(
    function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      return error;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! There was ALSO an issue with CORS. After following advices in this topic, I configured that as well and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

You did't inject the `categoriesService` into your controller, but instead injected a `dataService`. Try this

```
myApp.controller('CategoriesCtrl', function ($scope, categoriesService) {
        $scope.data = null;
        categoriesService.getData().then(function (response) {
            $scope.data = response;
        }, function (response) {
            alert(response.status);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the heads up! But the result remains the same, alert with "-1" message